# /dev/ttyUSB latency of 15ms

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty, ftdi

One byte of async serial takes < 0.1ms, on the wire, at 115200 baud.  (10 bits periods: START + 8 + STOP.)

The following C program:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L /* needed for CLOCK_MONOTONIC */
#include <termios.h> /* tcattr */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> /* strerror */
#include <errno.h> /* errno */
#include <fcntl.h> /* O_NDELAY, O_RDWR, O_EXCL */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */
#include <inttypes.h> /* PRIu64 */
#include <time.h> /* struct timespec */

int open_ttyusb(uint8_t n)
{
    char path[] = "/dev/ttyUSBnnn"; /* long enough for all values of uint8_t */
    sprintf(path, "/dev/ttyUSB%i", n);
    int fd = open(path, O_NDELAY|O_RDWR|O_EXCL);

    if (fd < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct termios t;

    tcgetattr(fd, &t);             /* save old one  */
    t.c_iflag = t.c_oflag = 0;
    t.c_cflag = B115200;

    t.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); /* always 8-bit and local (no modem controls) */
    t.c_cflag |= CS8;              /* 8 bit character size mask */

    t.c_iflag = IGNBRK;

    t.c_lflag = 0;
    t.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    t.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &t); /* do it all and flush input */
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);

    uint8_t rubbish[4096];
    while (read(fd, rubbish, 4096) > 0); /* make sure that there is nothing left */

    return fd;
}

uint64_t now(void) {
    struct timespec spec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec);
    return spec.tv_nsec + spec.tv_sec * 1000000000;
} 

int main(void) {
    int fd0 = open_ttyusb(0);
    int fd1 = open_ttyusb(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { /* repeat the test 10 times */
        uint64_t start = now();
        char tx = 'A' + i; /* send chars 'A' through 'J' */
        write(fd0, &tx, 1); 
        uint8_t rx;
        while (read(fd1, &rx, 1) < 1); /* loop until read succeeds */
        if (rx != 'A' + i) { /* check that we've read the right char */
            exit(-2);
        }
        uint64_t elapsed = now() - start;
        printf("time_taken: %"PRIu64".%"PRIu64"ms\n", elapsed / 1000000, elapsed % 1000000);
    }   
}
```

outputs:

```
time_taken: 1.292915ms
time_taken: 15.881472ms
time_taken: 15.859872ms
time_taken: 15.926402ms
time_taken: 15.975379ms
time_taken: 15.851588ms
time_taken: 15.882685ms
time_taken: 15.944355ms
time_taken: 15.915532ms
time_taken: 15.925496ms
```

(The first time_taken varies from 0-16ms, on each run.)

I have two USB FTDI adapters, wired together with RX and TX crossed over.

- Why does the byte take 15ms to get from one ttyUSB to the other?
- Why is the first transmission often much quicker?
- Can the code be changed to reduce the latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB1/latency_timer
```

beforehand, changes the output to:

```
time_taken: 0.702836ms
time_taken: 0.959548ms
time_taken: 1.2687ms
time_taken: 0.973790ms
time_taken: 0.994789ms
time_taken: 0.971454ms
time_taken: 1.12738ms
time_taken: 1.9920ms
time_taken: 0.986125ms
time_taken: 0.947801ms
```

which is much more acceptable.

While I have no proof, I'm guessing that this increases the rate at which the FTDI device is polled over USB.  (USB devices cannot initiate communications, they must be polled.)

Likewise, I'm guessing that the (original) quicker first response was due to the program being started just before ttyUSB1 was polled.

P.S. Echoing a zero into the `latency_timer` improves things further:

```
time_taken: 0.174095ms
time_taken: 0.350353ms
time_taken: 0.188431ms
time_taken: 0.175983ms
time_taken: 0.184215ms
time_taken: 0.197525ms
time_taken: 0.229502ms
time_taken: 0.201619ms
time_taken: 0.158024ms
time_taken: 0.150763ms
```

with a waveform of:

[image: serial waveform]

Comment: Sorry but I dont really see the "changes" you did to solve your question. 16 ms is btw the standard timeout for "to small" packages. At least the windows driver from FTDI trys to "batch" USB packets together. This can be dealt with by either ensure that always enough data is sent at once to fill a packet or by lowering the time out setting to the minimum.

Comment: @ChristianB. The change was to echo a value (1 or 0) into `/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSBn/latency_timer`.  This increases the polling rate and decreases the latency of received bytes.

Comment: If used protocol has a special "frame end" byte one can set it as `/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSBn/event_char`, and when the byte arrives the FTDI chip will flush its internal FIFO immediately not dependent on `latency_timer`.

Comment: Another note: some earlier FTDI chip did not support latency timer less then 2. Event character was the only way to reduce packet latency at the time.